# Iphone screen video capture

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, record

i've tried googling this but i can't get into an appropriate article for what i am looking for.

Obviously i am not asking for a solution here, just some direction regarding where to research for the following:

I was asked to write an app that should run in the background and record both the voice of the user and whatever shows on the screen.

For starters, is that even possible? If so, any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean recording *your* app or any running app? There's a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unless you are writing code for a jailbroken device. Apple would never allow this kind of app, even if you WERE able to do it.

Comment: on that note though, am i able to do it even if i don't want it published on the appstore?

Comment: Anything is possible, however I am not sure of the legal implications of doing this kind of thing on other peoples devices....

Comment: it will be volluntary, don't worry. :) since screen capture software are allowed in desktop computers, can't see why they would pose a problem in a mobile device. Do you happen to have any idea on where to research for such a venture?

Comment: I think that the simple reason is that your app is sandboxed, so when the user close your app nothing happens and  you can't capture anymore the video.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE1cUi9Zb5w 

the existence of this app begs to differ :)

Comment: sorry, maybe I have not explained well, that device of the video is jailbreaked. I thought you meant to develop the app for the store.

Comment: well that was my initial thought, but i was prepared to discover that it couldn't be done. But i'd like to know if it could be done even if my target group is jailbroken devices.